# How to find originating class name where exception was thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Give a simple reference to a `Throwable` object. I want to just find out what the original class where this was thrown. I no longer am inside this class so all I have is a `Throwable` object that was passed in from somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `GetStackTrace` property of `Throwable` to retreive `getClassName()`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

```
for (StackTraceElement ste : myThrowableObject.getStackTrace())
{
    System.out.println(ste.getClassName());
}
```

This will print all classes involved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried GetStackTrace() on your Throwable object?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetStackTrace( )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29)  to retrieve the class name.

> Provides programmatic access to the stack trace information printed by
>   printStackTrace().

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace will show the exception, but the exception may also have a cause, and so on.

The originating class is most likely the first stack trace element in the *last cause*, so you might want alter the collection logic according to your needs.

Here is how you can collect all involved classes in order of appearance.

```
Exception e = getTheException();
Set<String> classNames = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Throwable cause = e;
while (cause != null) {                      
    Stream.of(cause.getStackTrace()).forEach(element-> classNames.add(element.getClassName());
    cause = cause.getCause();
}
```